# What does it mean for the Leggett Inequality to falsify realism in general in Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leggett_inequality

As you can see in the above link, it claims that Bell's inequality ruled out local realism in quantum mechanics, and the violation of Leggett's inequalities is considered to falsify realism in general in quantum mechanics.

This would mean there is no material reality or objective reality! This is being said by Bernard Haisch as well, if I'm not mistaken.

Is this true, or is this false?

Comment: Yes, quantum mechanics rejects the classical notion of realism - while quantum mechanics is compatible with locality and many important QM models, like quantum field theories, imply exact locality. Bell's inequalities rule out local realism but there are many other (and stronger) thought-and-real experiments  etc. etc. that rule out huge classes of nonlocal realist theories, too. When taken together, realism is ruled out even without adjectives, and it's been really ruled out at the physics level of rigor for over 85 years. Sadly, too many popular books claim it's "locality" that's ruled out.

Comment: @LubošMotl A phrase such as "realism is ruled out" is a bit crazy unless you add some qualifiers to explain how the term "realism" is being used. QM does not rule out that there are real stars and real planets and real living things and real people etc. It is rather that the relationship between all those real things and the mathematical abstractions invoked in quantum theory, such as Hilbert space and wavefunctions, is  not as direct as the one we became accustomed to in classical physics.

Comment: @AndrewSteane There is a very simple way to prove realism: somebody should give us a formula for the arrival time of the next photon in our photomultiplier tubes. That is really all it takes. Until a physical realist has achieved that, the entire topic is of about as much importance in physics as the latest research into perpetual motion.

Comment: @FlatterMann was that a real photomultiplier tube you were referring to? And is it real people you refer to by "our"?

Comment: @AndrewSteane Of course. A photomultiplier is a wonderful experimental setup to exorcize physical realism. It just sits there and clicks randomly. I have not seen a single paper that claims to be able to predict the clicks, even thought it's the most trivial system one can think of in quantum mechanics.

Comment: @FlatterMann  The clicks are real.

Comment: @AndrewSteane Indeed. So is the fact that physical realists can't predict them. If we apply a put up or shut up rule, then the clicks shut everybody up very quickly. And this is indeed the exact same case as with perpetual motion. All it takes to invalidate the second and third laws of thermodynamics is one guy with a perpetual motion machine. Just one. Isn't it funny that we still haven't seen even one?

Comment: @FlatterMann We seem to agree the clicks are real. Greetings, fellow physical realist.

Comment: @AndrewSteane The clicks are real but they don't mean what the "realists" claim they mean. But, yes, if you want to call a physical realist someone who knows what is an actual physical phenomenon and what is merely philosophical nonsense, then, yes, then I am a realist.

Comment: Realism has a particular meaning in QM and it is ruled out, period. No time to chat with "realists" which is just a subset of laymen ignorant about physics (almost all of them).

Answer (score 2):

Bell's theorem is interesting because it makes few assumptions about the hidden-variable theory. Essentially, the measurement outcomes can depend in an arbitrary way on anything in the universe except for the setting of the other polarizer (and anything from which that could be deduced).

Leggett, in contrast, makes very specific assumptions. To be vulnerable to his argument, a model of a Bell pair must include as hidden variables two unit vectors $\def\a{\mathbf a} \def\b{\mathbf b} \def\u{\mathbf u} \def\v{\mathbf v} \u,\v$, and the independent measurement statistics of the particles in the Bell pair must match the QM prediction for unentangled states $|\u\rangle$ and $|\v\rangle$, for all polarizer settings $\a$ and $\b$. This is formalized in his equations (3.3a) and (3.3b):

$$\begin{align}
\int A(\a,\b,λ) \, g_{\u\v}(λ) dλ &= 2(\u\cdot\a)^2-1 \\
\int B(\a,\b,λ) \, g_{\u\v}(λ) dλ &= 2(\v\cdot\b)^2-1
\end{align}$$

where $A,B,λ$ have essentially the same meaning as in Bell, and $g_{\u\v}$ is a probability distribution like Bell's $ρ$, but it ranges only over the values of $λ$ that include a specific $\u$ and $\v$. These equalities hold for all $\u,\v,\a,\b$.

I don't see why a hidden variable theory should be expected to have this form. It makes some sense to require it in the special case $\u=\a$ (likewise $\v=\b$), where it expresses that $\u$ ($\v$) is the true polarization of the particle. To account for experimental reality, it would need to hold approximately for $\u\approx\a$. But when $\u$ and $\a$ are arbitrarily misaligned, you aren't measuring the true polarization, and I see no reason to expect the quantum relationship (for, again, a *different system* than the one being modeled here) to apply.

I think that Bohmian mechanics doesn't even satisfy the special case $\u=\a$, since it has definite real values only for position, not arbitrary observables. Yet most people think that Bohmian mechanics is a realistic model.

Comment: Bohmian mechanics can't predict position, either. I never understood why this rumor is around that it can.

Comment: @FlatterMann If you mean it's impossible to measure positions precisely enough to predict future positions, I think that's no secret. Everyone calls it a hidden variable theory, and that's the hidden part. But the Bohmian position is the real position in the sense that if you have an array of Geiger counters, the one that clicks is the one where the particle is.

Comment: If we have an array of detectors, then the one that clicks is always the one that absorbs a quantum of energy. That is merely a physical fact and hence independent of the theoretical description. Copenhagen doesn't claim anything else with the Born rule, either. Bohmian mechanics can't predict anything beyond Copenhagen, but it needs to dance six times around the fire pit and introduce a mythical creature to come to the same conclusion. I would call that supernaturalism, at best.

Comment: @FlatterMann I don't necessarily disagree, but I only mentioned Bohmian mechanics in my answer because it's the only quasi-successful hidden variable theory that I know of, so it seemed relevant.